# 404 on nginx for a PATH

Tags: nginx

I have a website (say https://test.somesite.com) served from a /var/www/mainSite folder using nginx.
I have another website in https://test.somesite.com/CMS/ for which i have to keep another set of static files in /var/www/subSite

In my nginx config file i have below

```
root /var/www/mainSite;
 location / {
          if (!-e $request_filename){
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
         }
        }
location /CMS/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /subSite/index.html break;
    }
}
```

Though the mainSite works properly, i get a 404 when i hit /CMS/

In nginx logs i see,
*544213 open() "/var/www/mainSite/subSite/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.31.77.145, server: test.somesite.com, request: "GET /CMS/ HTTP/1.1", host: "test.somesite.com"

Not able to get what is going wrong here. Can someone help me understand the issue? So that next time i am not doing the same :)

Comment: Does the file `/var/www/mainSite/subSite/index.html` exist? What file do you expect the URI `/subSite/index.html` to return?

Comment: ``/var/www/mainSite/subSite/index.html `` here nothing exists as both my mainSite and subSite folders are at a same level. They are 2 different websites 1 served on somesite.com/ and other on somesite.com/CMS/ @RichardSmith

Comment: If the `index.html` file is in `/var/www/subSite`, you should try: `alias /var/www/subSite/;` within the `location /CMS/` block. And `rewrite ^ /CMS/index.html last;` within the `if` block.